# how to write simple query into codeigniter query using join right

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

how to write simple query into codeigniter query using join righ?????

```
$query = $this->db->query("Select staff_permissions_list.perm_type,staff_permissions_list.permission_key,staff_permissions_list.permission_label,
        staff_permissions_list.id, staff_role_permissions.permission_id as p_id,staff_role_permissions.role_id
                                FROM staff_role_permissions 
                                RIGHT JOIN staff_permissions_list ON staff_role_permissions.permission_id=staff_permissions_list.id 
                                AND staff_role_permissions.role_id=$id WHERE staff_permissions_list.perm_type=0
                                ORDER BY staff_permissions_list.id ASC
                                ");
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    return $query->result_array();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('book_id, book_name, author_name, category_name');
$this->db->from('books');
$this->db->join('category', 'category.category_id = books.category_id', 'right');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

you can get data using this method of right join

Comment: your query is not return all data from category .. only return match data

Comment: you can pass select (*) condition to get all data or another way is mention all filed in select condition

Answer (score 0):

How about that ?

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select("Select staff_permissions_list.perm_type,staff_permissions_list.permission_key,staff_permissions_list.permission_label,staff_permissions_list.id, staff_role_permissions.permission_id as p_id,staff_role_permissions.role_id")
    ->from("staff_role_permissions AS srp")
    ->join("staff_permissions_list AS spl","srp.permission_id = spl.id","right")
    ->where("spl.perm_type","0")
    ->where("srp.role_id",$id)
    ->order_by("spl.id","ASC")
    ->get();
```

i put the role_id to the where section - maybe you need to put it back (not sure what you want to achieve here)